# Does Grails v1.1.1 support multiple database connections?

Tags: grails, database-connection, grails-plugin

Currently I am using Grails v1.1.1. I need to connect multiple databases.

So I need to know if it's possible to connect to multiple DB's in Grails v1.1.1.

What is the procedure to connect multiple DB's?
Are there any plugins required?

If so, please share the link.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the datasources plugin.

> grails install-plugin datasources

**UPDATE**

Datasources plugin is no longer available.

Comment: I traied this 
then I got Plugin 'datasources' was not found in repository. If it is not stored in a confi
gured repository you will need to install it manually. Type 'grails list-plugins
' to find out what plugins are available.

Comment: I think you should be more than lucky to find any repos for Grails 1.x still out there. It's way outdated, and I can only recommend to move to Grails 3.x - even though it's probably a bit effort to do so.

Comment: as @sbglasius has said you really should upgrade. I managed to track down a later version than official 0.5 here https://github.com/stefankendall/grails-datasources-0.5-fixes  so maybe you can install it locally. Interestingly your profile photo said Be brave in your life. I certainly think you should be taking own advice and be brave enough to face the upgrade hurdle

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions & Compliments @sbglasius, #vahid